# detect react scrolled to bottom element. scrollTop

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ecmascript-6

What to do to access the scroll handler's event? can't access to offsetTop, scrollTop etc

```
    class App extends React.Component {
      handleScroll = e => {
        console.log(e.target.scrollTop);
      };
      componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
      }
      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <h1 style={{ height: "1000px" }}>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
            <h1>Hello end</h1>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

[Codesabdbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-meitner-mu5l1)

Comment: What does the console output? The example codesandbox doesn’t allow scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

You can still access the traditional window methods to help determine whether you reached the bottom. Here's your updated code and sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-poitras-04g3h

We can employ state to configure the appearance of the component when we reach the bottom.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    endReached: false
  };
  handleScroll = () => {
    if (
      window.scrollY + window.innerHeight >= document.body.offsetHeight &&
      !this.state.endReached
    ) {
      this.setState({
        endReached: true
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        endReached: false
      });
    }
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className={this.state.endReached ? "end-reached" : ""}>
        <h1 style={{ height: "1000px" }}>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h1>Hello end</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.documentElement` to access `scrollTop`:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  handleScroll = e => {
    console.log(document.documentElement.scrollTop);
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 style={{ height: "1000px" }}>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h1>Hello end</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.I hope it will works.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  handleScroll = e => {
    const winScroll =
      document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    console.log("scrolled=========>", winScroll);
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.listenToScroll);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 style={{ height: "1000px" }}>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h1>Hello end</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```